# decimal to hex in assembler

Tags: assembly, hex, decimal

The system I'm working with, has four registers: al, bl, cl, dl and values can be stored only as hex.

I am reading from keyboard 2 digits, e.g. 9 and 1.

I would like to store this number in the BL register, as 5B which is the hex value for 91 (decimal).

I've been thinking of ways to solve this, but I can't find any. My main mistake was I was multiply 9 by 10, and add 1, result is 91, but I've forgot that actually 91 is in hex, which translated to decimal becomes 145 (which is not my number)

So, how do I store the two digits (9 and 1, which form 91) as hex value (5B) into some register or in RAM.

Please advise.

Many thanks, 
V

Comment: Hex is just a human-readable representation of a value; I'm pretty sure you don't want to "store as hex value in some register".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My main mistake was I was multiply 9 by 10, and add 1, result is 91, but I've forgot that actually 91 is in hex

That's not a mistake. As long as you are multiplying by 10 (decimal) and not 10h (hex, which is 16 decimal), then you'll get the answer you are looking for.

Values stored in CPU registers are just binary numbers, they aren't "in hex" or "in decimal".

Note that you may occasionally run into [BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal), which aren't binary numbers but are another thing entirely.

Answer (score 3):

The number isn't stored as hex, decimal or whatever, it's up to you to interpret it as such when you want to do something like creating a human-readable string of the value in the register.

The integer value `91 in decimal = 5B in hex = 1011011 in binary`, it's all stored the same way in the register - as a binary value.

Since you're taking in input as decimal, then it's right for you to multiply 9 by 10 and then to add the 1 in order to end up with the decimal number 91 (or interpreted as hex - 5B).

Be careful if the input is the ASCII representation (or any other encoding) of the character `'9'`, in which case you'll need to convert the code to the actual decimal value. If it is in fact an ASCII value then you'd just subtract the character `'0'` to get the decimal number 9.

When you want to interpret the binary value of the register as hex for perhaps printing, you'd build up the string by repeatedly getting the remainder of dividing the value in the register by 16, [as outlined here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Division-remainder_in_source_base). It's the same process for constructing a decimal string (divide by 10) or a binary string (divide by 2).

Comment: Thanks @AusCBloke, the system I'm actually on, it's storing ONLY as hex, never as decimal.

I'm in the situation where I put 9 in one register, multiply it by 10 (but this 10 is hex), and then I add a 1. The result I see "looks" decimal, 91, but in reality it's 145 (the decimal equivalent).

So, question, how do I actually convert the 9 and the 1 to hexadecimal.

Comment: @VladimirGhetau: I think you've misread this answer.  The value is NOT stored as decimal or hex.  Either you have performed the wrong calculation, or you are misinterpreting the content of the register.

Comment: @VladimirGhetau: The values stored in a register are simply a sequence of 1's and 0's, you can interpret this value as hex, decimal, binary, octal, or any sort of number system that you like. It may just be that whatever program you're using to view the values in the registers represents those values as hex for convenience, since a byte can be represented by 2 hexadecimal digits. As Oli has mentioned, you must for some reason be multiplying the value in the register by 10h rather than 10d, or the value in the register is actually 91d.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you was multiplying by 10h (which is 16 in dec), so it was producing wrong results.

```
   ;assuming val_1 is 9h and val_2 is 1h

   mov al, val_1
   mul al, 0Ah
   add al, val_2
   mov bl, al
```